# Elasticseach highlighting with single set of pre and post tags for multi-word phrase search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, information-retrieval

I am trying to run an elasticsearch `match_phrase` query along with the plain highlighter. I need to search for the multi-word phrases. The issue is that the `pre` and `post` tags get appended for each word in the multi-word phrase. Is there a way to output only one set of `pre` and `post` tags around the complete phrase?

e.g. Searching for "lorem ipsum", currently gives me:

```
<em>lorem</em> <em>ipsum</em>
```

And I want to get following highlighting:

```
<em>lorem ipsum</em>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the "fvh" highlighter. Try "plain" instead.

Comment: I am using the default highlighter, which is "plain"  according to the Elasticsearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-highlighting.html#plain-highlighter).